# Returning objects or multiple variables (not numbers) in R

Tags: r, return, svm, return-type

I am training multiple SVMs in my R application, and I would like my function to return a holder object to which I can easily access each one of them later in a function.

The SVM is created as this:

```
svm.model <- svm(x=trainset,y=trainlabels)
svm.pred <- predict(svm.model,testset)

res <- table(pred = svm.pred, true = testlabels)
```

I want to be able to return the table called "res", or both svm.model and svm.pred. Any will do.

In a Object Oriented language I would use something like Javas ArrayList to do this, but a regular list(which was suggested in many posts) didn't do its job. I was not able to put any of these values, and if I made it, they got "unwrapped" and lost its structure.

**Update**
Good point in the comment section about how exactly I tried to do this with a list. I did the following:

```
result<-list()

for i in...
   result[i]<-svm.model
   result[i+1] <-svm.pred
```

I have tried the same as above, but with "res"(a table).

Another approach I tried was to create a new list with the previous list each time:
    result<-list(result,svm.model,svm.pred)

It gives me only a length 3 size list(I see why) and the two last values are "lists" instead of what they are in fact, hence it doesn't allow me to call "table(pred = svm.pred, true = testlabels) " as it returns an error:

"Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?"

Comment: A `list` is *the* way to do this. Look at how many R functions return `list`s (or classes that are, essentially, `list`s with additional structure). If a `list` "didn't do its job", then it would be good if you could post a reproducible example showing what exactly does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a loop and you want to store all three

```
result<-list()
for (i in 1:n) {
    ...
    svm.model <- svm(x=trainset,y=trainlabels)
    svm.pred <- predict(svm.model,testset)

    res <- table(pred = svm.pred, true = testlabels)  
    result[[i]] <- list(res=res, svm.model=svm.model, svm.pred=svm.pred)
}
```

Note is is important to use `[[ ]]` when putting items into a list and getting them out. I also used a named list here to make it easier to get specific objects out. Then if you wanted to re-make the table from the 3rd loop, you could do

```
table(pred = result[[3]]$svm.pred, true=testlabels)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer! I managed to overcome it also by doing the following:

```
result[folders[i]]<-list(res)
```

Where folders is a vector of names. :-)

Comment: `result[[ folders[i] ]] <- res` makes a bit more sense